# Cannot access POST method by url

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to access POST function.
My URL is `http://localhost:7186/api/values/Post/asss` but in Chrome browser by pressing F12 in network request monitor, the type of request generated is `GET` and the function returns me the value which I want to get. I have already use `FromBody` in function parameter. The code of `Post` in controller is as I am passing string parameter in url link.

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody] String val)
{
    string str = "hello";
    return str;
}
```

P.S: I am getting HTTP 404 Error

Comment: How are you trying to test this on chrome? If you put the url on address bar you'll generete a GET request always, and this won't work since that method only accepts POST. If you want to test a POST request, you could use a tool like fiddler.

Comment: Can u tell me more about fiddler

Comment: @ClaudioRedi also can u tell why i am getting 404 error

Comment: you're getting a 404 error because there is no method accepting GET request type named `POST`

Comment: This google search may help you https://www.google.com/search?q=fiddler&oq=fiddler&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4879j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=fiddler+web+api+post

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test HTTP POST from browsers address bar. (Chrome has extension like POSTMAN for such kind of testing). You can also use a tool like fiddler.

Download fiddler http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

1. Open Fiddler, on the right go "Compose" tab.
2. Put URL as `http://localhost:7186/api/values`(Not sure how you assigned this `http://localhost:7186/api/values/Post/asss`. Just remove it for testing, you can add it later).
3. To its left there is a HTTP VERB drop down. Choose "POST".
4. In the Request body part put any string.
5. Hit "Execute".
6. On the left you should see your URL and HTTP 200 code if there is no error. Double click it, you should be able to explore the result.